# Add facebook permission after user is already authorized

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, authorization

I have an app that had the basic facebook permissions.
Now, in my new update I need to ask the user for a new (email) permission and I can't find a way to add a permission after the user has already authorized the basic permissions.
Is there a simple way of doing it? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a class called NewPermissionsRequest. You prepare this request (check it, it is simple). Then use your old session to request this new permission. For example, use `session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);` for new Publish Permissions.

Comment: why do you not put it as an answer?

Comment: Be careful with facebook stuff. Test again and again: Cancel authorization and then retry; Kill the app and test. You should test as many situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a class called [NewPermissionsRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session.NewPermissionsRequest/).

You prepare this request (check it, it is simple).

Then use your old session to request this new permission. For example, use session.[requestNewPublishPermissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session/#requestNewPublishPermissions%28NewPermissionsRequest%29)(newPermissionsRequest); for new Publish Permissions.